# UAP - RelativePanel setters lead to Unhandled and AccessViolation exceptions

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

With the following XAML code:

```
<RelativePanel x:Name="MainPanel"/>
```

And the following C# code:

```
var _red = new Rectangle() {
    Width = _res.X, Height = _res.Y / 2, Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
};
var _blue = new Rectangle() {
    Width = _res.X, Height = _res.Y / 2, Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)
};
MainPanel.Children.Add(_red); MainPanel.Children.Add(_blue);

RelativePanel.SetAlignTopWithPanel(_red, true); // (a)
RelativePanel.SetAlignLeftWithPanel(_red, true); // (b)
RelativePanel.SetBelow(_blue, _red); // (c)
```

I've got 2 different exceptions: at the lines (a) & (b), I've got an `AccessViolationException`, with the additionnal information: `Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`.

At the line (c), so if I remove the two previous, VS's JIT debugger tells me that `An unhandled win32 exception occured in foo.exe [10984]`. Which is probably an error code, but I didn't find any documentations about it.

Any clues of why this is happenning, and how to fix this ? Moreover, if I set these properties within XAML it works fine.

Comment: It happened to me the same but only in the Phone, in the Local machine works: http://bit.ly/1JyD40j. I have tested to place it in Loaded, in a Dispatcher but no success

Comment: Indeed I replied in the feedback app in the Universal Apps, might be I should chose UI Frameworks and XAML

Comment: Well for me the problem happen both in Desktop (build 10049) and Phone (lumia 1520, v10.0.12534.56). I also reported it within the feedback form, I hope this issue will be known and corrected asap.

Comment: At the moment I was able to make it work in the designer with: RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="{Binding ElementName=grid1}" a binding instead the element name... smashing. Might be by this way but I have achieved anything else.

Comment: For me it was always working when I set the property in the designer, even without binding. It just doesn't work through code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this issue has been fixed both for Desktop and Phone, with the new build 10061.